# Images not loading on route with params but works on routes without params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-router, react-router-dom

Hello for some reason I am having a problem where images won't load on routes with params. Yet on any route without params they load just fine.

so for example I load route '/product/:id';

that component for that route contains this

```
class Product extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        product: null
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchProduct();
}

fetchProduct() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;

    axios.get(`/api/product/${id}`).then(function (response) {
        this.setState({ product: response.data });
    }.bind(this));
}

renderProduct() {
    let { product } = this.state;

    if (!product) {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-md-5'>
                    <img src={product.main_img} />//this image is not displaying
                    <h5>{product.title}</h5>
                    <p>{product.description}</p>
                </div>
                <div className='col-md-5'>
                    <Form product={product}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            {this.renderProduct()}
        </div>
    )
 }
}
```

Ok so all the information for that product shows correctly and I can console.log(product.main_img) and that is the correct image. So why isn't the image showing? I have the exact same image on another route without params that shows fine. I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: What is logged for `product.main_img`?

Comment: The correct path for that image. I'm storing images locally in a folder called images so it's something like "./images/img-file.png"

Comment: I have never had this problem before and have done something like this many times. I heard of using require for webpack but I don't think I need that because like I said the same image works on other pages/routes without params.

Comment: Well, there is the issue with the image URL being relative to the current path. I'm guessing that the "images" folder is at the site root, and the image url should be `"/images/img-file.png"`. With the current URL in `product.main_img`, the browser resolves the image source to `/api/product/<id>/./images/img-file.png` which norms to `/api/product/<id>/images/img-file.png`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yep that was the problem. Changing "./images/img-file.png" to "/images/img-file.png" solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problems, I fixed it but changing all my links to images to start with a slash '/' then directory name instead of './' or just the directory name.

Comment: Did you read the comments below the question? If so what new information does your answer bring to the question?

Comment: @JasonAller the solutions shouldnt be in the comments